# angular2 How to select all？

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
class Heroe{
    selected ?: boolean;
}    


heroes: Observable<Heroe[]>
....
this.heroes = this.heroService.getHeroes()
....
select_all(){
    How to do it?
}
```

=======

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async" >
  <span *ngIF="hero.selected">selected</span>
  {{hero.name}}
</div>
<input type="checkbox" #checkbox (change)="select_all(checkbox.checked)">
```

**How to select？**
**How to select？**
**How to select？**
**How to select？**
**How to select？**
**How to select？**

Comment: Where are the heroes data coming from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.heroes = this.heroes.map(heroes => heroes.map(hero => ({...hero, selected})));
```